# REST APIs with R Plumber - GIS Shapefiles

Tags: r, rest, r-raster, rgdal, plumber

I am trying to wrap a function into REST API using plumber R Package. As a Input , function takes a shapefile and returns shapefile in terms of .shp format as well as GeoJSON format after the transformation. With the help of decorator now I need to enhance it into a web service.

**R File:**

```
#* Spatial Polygon Object 
#* @param pathtoshpfile:character Path to Shapefile with Name
#* @param design:character one or two
#* @post /sprayermap

function(pathtoshpfile, design = c("one", "two")) {
# library
require(rgeos)
require(sp)
require(rgdal)
require(raster)

#Importing Shapefile
a_shape <- raster::shapefile(pathtoshpfile)

if (class(a_shape) == "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame") {
if (design == "one") {
  a_shape <- tryCatch (
    rgeos::gBuffer(a_shape, byid = TRUE, width = 0),
    error = function(err) {
      return(paste("sprayer map : ", err))
      
    }
  )
  
  sprayer_map <- tryCatch (
    aggregate(a_shape, "Rx"),
    error = function(err) {
      return(paste("sprayer map : ", err))
      
    }
  )
  
  sprayer_map@data$Rx <- as.integer(sprayer_map@data$Rx)
  
  raster::shapefile(sprayer_map, filename = "field_sprayer_map", overwrite =
                      TRUE)
  rgdal::writeOGR(
    sprayer_map,
    dsn = "field_sprayer_map.GeoJSON",
    layer = "geojson",
    driver = "GeoJSON",
    overwrite_layer = TRUE
  )
  
  return(paste0("SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"))
  
} else {
  return(paste0("design two"))
}

} else {
return(paste0("Please provide spatial polygon object !"))

 }
}
```

**Plumber Part :**

```
library(plumber)
# 'plumber.R' is the location of the file shown above
pr("plumber.R") %>%
pr_run(port=8000)

#############################
curl "http://127.0.0.1:8000/sprayermap?pathtoshpfile=/path/to/directory/test.shp&design=one"
```

Based on my limited understanding on creation of APIs , I created above script and got below error.

*Error: unexpected string constant in "curl "http://127.0.0.1:8000/sprayermap?*

Though plain R Function script works good

Looking for guidance how the decorators can be used to convert the above function into Restful APIs where Input and output both are shapefiles.
Test Shape File: [Test Shape File](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dbJks-6H-Yb3r4CNJ7yeSlsX4YmOAkw7?usp=sharing)

Comment: did you try with `@get /sprayermap`?

Comment: @inscaven yeah same issue Error: unexpected string constant in "curl

Answer (score 1):

I believe your function is setup correctly. The following `curl` calls should help you out:

```sh
curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8000/sprayermap?pathtoshpfile=../Downloads/jnk/test.shp&design=one"
```

(ie. insert `-X POST` in your existing call). Alternatively, via `--data`:

```sh
curl --data "pathtoshpfile=../Downloads/jnk/test.shp" "http://127.0.0.1:8000/sprayermap"
```

On my machine, both queries return

```sh
["SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"]
```

and `field_sprayer_map` is written to disk. For the record, this works with both the current **plumber** CRAN version 0.4.6:

```r
p = plumb("../Downloads/jnk/plumber.R")
p$run(port=8000)
```

And the upcoming [v1.0.0 release candidate](https://twitter.com/schloerke/status/1296915681892597761):

```r
pr("../Downloads/jnk/plumber.R") %>%
  pr_run(port=8000)
```

Comment: Thank you fdetsch. The local swagger generated worked for me and it gave the output as you suggested function looks good. For me curl still gives issue - Error: unexpected symbol in "curl -X POST" . I am using RStudio Server configured in ubuntu machine and using 0.4.9 rstudio version of plumber. It seems I am doing some silly mistake. Any Idea ?

Comment: Can you share your `curl -X POST` call?

Comment: Hello , need your suggestion / guidance to have GeoJSON as request body as Input - json body or json file in POST request plumber API instead of shapefile path. If needed I can share reproducible example. Thank you.